# NSSpeechRecognizer with wildcard command elements

Tags: objective-c, speech-recognition

The docs for NSSpeechRecognizer state that complex, multi-step actions can be executed from single spoken commands, such as:

> “schedule a meeting with Adam and John tomorrow at ten o’clock.”

I'm able to execute simple commands which are preprogrammed, but I don't see how the above could be interpreted using the class.  It seems like

> “schedule a * with * *”

should be a command.  Any idea if something like this is possible?  Or are we just supposed to pass an infinite number of possible commands to the recognizer?

Comment: Did you ever get any authoritative info on this?

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear to me from the NSSpeechRecognizer documentation that it will support using complex phrases like the example you have given.  To get the semantic meaning from a phrase like this you would use a system that supports [multislot grammars](http://docs.voxeo.com/voicexml/n2.0/frame.jsp?page=grxmlmultislot.htm) like most IVR systems that support the VoiceXML standard. It looks to me that this speech recognition API only supports passing in simple commands as an array and not specifying complex grammar rules.  With this type of system you would have to implement what is called a directed dialog, which might go something like this:

C: What would you like to do?

U: Schedule a meeting.

C: Tell me the first person that you would like to attend?

U: Adam.

C: Tell me the next person that will attend or say "done" if the attendee list is complete.

U: John.

C: Tell me the next person that will attend or say "done" if the attendee list is complete.

U: Done.

C: What day is this meeting?

U: Tomorrow.

C: What time is the meeting?

U: Ten O'Clock.

C: Thank you. Your meeting has been scheduled.

Using a directed dialog you can restrict the expected commands/utterances to a much more defined list.  Although your list of possible names could be quite large unless you cull them from a users contact list.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the docs is that you would need to accumulate and operate on any compound state on your own.  You provide NSSpeechRecognizer with a set of discrete words/phrases that it should recognize as 'commands', and it reports to you when it has recognized them.

For the example you've given, I think you'll run into problems when you get to the "Adam and John" part -- it's not an arbitrary dictation engine.  But, for fun, let's try to imagine how we might do this:

You might tell it you want to recognize the following phrases as 'commands':

- "schedule a"
- "meeting" (and perhaps "appointment", "playdate", etc)
- "with"
- "Adam and John"
- "tomorrow" (and probably other related things like "today", "two days from now", all the days of the week, etc)
- "ten o'clock"

As words/phrases are recognized, you could create a stack of semantically related words/phrases based on previously recognized words/phrases.  So, for instance, it recognizes the "schedule a" phrase, and you know that there should be more info coming to fill out the semantic context, so you push that phrase onto the stack. Next, it recognizes "meeting". Your app says 'sure, a meeting is something that can be scheduled' and pushes it onto the stack as well. If the next word it recognized *wasn't* germane to the previously-recognized "schedule a" command, then it would clear the stack. If, at any point, the elements on the stack satisfy some pre-defined criteria for a fully formed expression of semantic intent, then your app can take the appropriate action based on that intent. There's obviously a temporal element to this as well. If the next thing required to establish semantic context doesn't arrive in a reasonable amount of time, the semantic context stack should get cleared.

A similar system, conceptually, is the iOS/MacOS touch/trackpad gesture recognition system.  When a tap touch happens, the OS has to recognize the single tap, and acknowledge the possibility that that is the entire user intent, but it also has to manage the possibility that it might receive another tap very shortly, turning the single tap into a double tap.  It will have to accumulate this state over time, and infer the user intent by looking at the combination of discrete events.

You're not going to get such functionality from NSSpeechRecognizer for free, and being that it's not a dictation engine, you also won't get arbitrary 'tokens' from it (like "Adam and John", assuming you're not registering some giant list of names all as potential commands.)  Even so, that doesn't mean it couldn't be leveraged to do some pretty neat stuff using a mechanism like I described.  It's just that you're gonna have to write it yourself.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your thoughtful feedback.  I believe that we are in agreement but I am waiting for an authoritative response on whether there is some designated approach to this problem other than "infinite commands".  If none comes, I will accept your answer as correct (since it in all likeliness is).

Comment: From my experience, `NSSpeechRecognizer` can only detect _whole phrases_ that you set it to listen for. Using your given command list, a person would have to say: "Schedule a" (wait a second for processing) "meeting" (wait a second) . . . which is not what you want. Whereas if you set the command list to something like: "Schedule a meeting with Adam and John", etc. this would work properly.

Comment: My answer was simply an attempt to explore how you might take a system that could only detect whole phrases and bend it around to do something like what the original question asked.